# Automate creation of a SharePoint list without writing any code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-list, sharepointadmin

As part of the configuration of my product (after installation), I need to create a few Sharepoint lists on the SharePoint site specified by the user.

Digging around, it seems that i need to write custom code to do this, either using the server-side API as described at http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-sharepoint-list-programmatically.html, or using the SharePoint List web services. But in both cases, I need to write code to do this.

Is there any out-of-box way to do this, without writing any code? My ideal solution would be to create an XML file which has the appropriate definition, and then run *something* (passing in the SharePoint site url), which would then create the list, and return a status code indicating success or failure. Is such an ideal solution possible?

If not, what is the best/easiest solution to do this? One of the two above, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Create a feature specifying a ListInstance, when you activate the feature, the list will be created:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx

Comment: This is definitely the best and easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the feature as Vladi said.

But you can also install the STSADM extensions from Gary Lapointe. It includes a [command to create a list](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/07/add-list.html). You can then write a batch file that creates all the lists in 1 go.